# How to add a border to a cell upon clicking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

My goal is to make a border when a cell is clicked on by a user.

This code below works:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
```

Then I added this code in order to make the border colored but it had no effect.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell : MKStandItemAdd = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MKStandItemAdd
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 7
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
```

This code above still prints, but it didnt change the color.

so I added:

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

But now nothing happens at all. It no longer prints and it doesnt reload the collection.

Comment: don't call reloadData(). reload specific cell .

Comment: when you clicks on cell .. store that index and than according to index make a border in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method

Comment: Try add `cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple solution that I found after reading the 1st 2 comments

```
    let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell!.layer.borderWidth = 7
    cell!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Set directly to cell on `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` will not there when you reload or scroll the cell.

The better way to do that is inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where the cell is rendered.

First, we need to have a class variable

```
var selectedRow = -1
```

So in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to check for the selected row index

```
// check if selected
if indexPath.row == selectedRow {
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 7
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
}
else {
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
}
```

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` need to reload the cell

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cellfotitemAtIndexPath` write

```
if(cell.isselected)
{
cell.layer.borderWidth = 7
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
}
else
{
//No border and no border color
}
```

in `DidSelectitemAtIndexPath`

reload you collection view